# Значение null при обращении к JSON через Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, null

Собственно вопрос, что не так? :-). Все работает, но значение не выводит. Пишет значение "null" в строке sb.

Вот сам код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    private void getArtist(){

        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        MusicInterface musicInterface = retrofit.create(MusicInterface.class);
        Call call = musicInterface.getArtist("artist.getinfo","Cher","6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be", "json");
        call.enqueue(new Callback () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

                if (response.body() !=null) {
                    Artist artist = (Artist) response.body();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(artist.getName());

                    textView.setText(sb);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void StartBtn(View view) {
        getArtist();
    }
```

Класс значений Artist:

```
public class Artist {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> image = null;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

Где неправильно обращаюсь?

Comment: Выведите в логи что у вас в `response.body()`. Также вам надо к TextView образаться в главном потоке - сейчас у вас из-за этого будет приложение падать на строке `textView.setText(sb);
`

Comment: Вот я, честно говоря, сам бы хотел это знать, что у меня в логах response.body()... Могу привести логи Logcat из Android Studio. Эти пойдут?

Comment: Попробуйте как-то так в logCat вывести: `System.out.println("data: "+response.body())`. Также можно HttpLoggingInterceptor подключить чтобы все данные запроса в логи выводились.

Comment: Хорошо. Попробую, но честно говоря, смутил меня вот такой набор сообщений в LogCat: java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
        at eyw.a(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:14)
        at eyw.a(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:65)
        at eyu.a(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:8)
        at eyq.a(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:1)
        at eyp.a(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@11743470:7)

Comment: Скорее всего запрос не верный и сервер выдаёт другой json с пояснением ошибки. Выводить body в лог бесполезно - потому что там будет ваш `Artist` с `null`-значениями в полях. Прикрутите лучше `HttpLoggingInterceptor` (как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827) и смотрите в LogCat что отвечает сервер. А то что вы показали вряд ли имеет отношение к вашему приложению (желательно включить фильтры в LogCat, чтобы не рыться во всём выхлопе устройства)

Comment: Когда организовывал предварительную проверку, т.е. после строки "Artist artist = (Artist) response.body();" вписывал "Ok" для TextView без формирования строки по запросу, то все работало.  И писало "Ok". Значит, строка "Artist artist = (Artist) response.body();" работает. По HttpLoggingInterceptor буду организовывать.

Comment: Нашел вот такой вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168155/ioexception-while-requesting-key-invalid-device-key-response

Comment: Буду пробовать. НО только завтра отпишусь.

Comment: Запрос оказался верным. И response приходит ненулевой. По HTTP пришёл 200-й респонс. Значит все работает :-). Response закинул в строку и создал класс ArtisInfo: public class ArtistInfo {
    @SerializedName("artist")
    @Expose
    private Artist artist;

    public Artist getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }
}

Comment: Если просто запускать отдельно Java-классами, то работает. Если через Android Studio, то выскакивает очень интересная ошибка: android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy

Comment: Это что может быть?